# What does it mean when your DBContext is disposed?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I get this error:

> *The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.  Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The
>   operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed*

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: Check out [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) and the [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement. You  probably tried to use your [`DBContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.103).aspx) object outside of the `using` in which it was defined _or_ after explicitly calling `Dispose()` upon it.

Comment: When do you get this error?

Comment: Can you please debug your code and find where the issue is happening. Then you can post some code for us to see.

Comment: What is the function of the dispose method because i used it in my controller

Comment: I get this error when i debug my project on my localhost,only occurs on  one table i retrieve data from using entity framework

Comment: @user2750775 The actual details of [`Dispose()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) vary with implementation... but in general, it _"Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources._" ... as I placed in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18637228/621962).

Comment: Do you have a `static` context somewhere in your app?

Comment: No my context is private

Answer (score 1):

> **What does it mean?**

It means that you can't continue using your [`DBContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) object. `DBContext` implements [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx); so, it has a [`Dispose()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) method which:

> Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.

So,

> **Why was it disposed?**

`Dispose()` was called explicitly by something, somewhere or it was called implicitly upon exiting a [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) block.

Comment: This is the code i have in my Controller:                                                                   protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

Comment: private Sprint5Entities db = new Sprint5Entities();

Comment: @canon When someone hasn't posted enough information in the question to answer it then it means you should vote to close the question, not provide a little bit of information as an answer that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @canon And it seems pretty clear that there's more to the problem than just that title.  You can't give more with the information given, and what you have given isn't enough to make this a good answer.  That's why you shouldn't have answered to begin with, you should have closed the question, because with the information here it's not *possible* to give a sufficiently good answer.  We need to wait for the OP to provide enough information.

Answer (score 1):

Your DbContext has been closed and disposed and you get the error probably because of lazy loading which files after the dbcontext is disposed. Is your DbContext wrapped in a using statement? if so then it's being disposed before the call to the DB

Comment: No my DB doesn't use the using statement

Comment: Can you add your code please @user2750775 to help us to help you. cheers

Comment: @skyfoot If you feel that the question has insufficient information to provide an adequate answer you should vote/flag to close, rather than trying to answer it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your DbContext Connection is closed and disposed prior to use.
try toput your code inside using block

```
using(MyDbContext objDbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
  //Put your code here.

}
```